# Am not receiving the desired status code from url after Posting as json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have my code like this

```
var contentData = new StringContent(allData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit", contentData);
var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BursaryTransactions>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

where `allData` is my json serialized object.

`BursaryTransactions` is a model class that has the properties "status", "RRR", "statuscode".

My objective is to post my content as json to a payment gateway (Remita) and in return receive a statuscode 025 and RRR.

```
https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit
```

is Remita demo api site with a  jsonp response code as

```
({"statuscode":"025","RRR":"260007663696","status":"Payment Reference generated"}).
```

After running the program, I want my object `msg`to hold the Remita response rather i got a status code of 200.

What is it am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the brackets part pf the response? This looks like a simple JSON deserialization. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Also do not mix async-await and blocking calls like `.Result` that can potentially cause deadlocks.

Comment: Yes the response is exactly what i want to retrieve and am not getting such response.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not mix async-await and blocking calls like `.Result` that can potentially cause deadlocks.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

This looks like a simple JSON deserialization

```
var contentData = new StringContent(allData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
string url = "https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit";
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, contentData);
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BursaryTransactions>(responseData);

string statuscode = msg.statuscode; //check for 025
string RRR = msg.RRR;
```

This assumes

```
public class BursaryTransactions {
    public string statuscode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string RRR { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ```public class BursaryTransactions {
    public string statuscode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string RRR { get; set; }
}``` Yes